# Retrieving real values from MS sql server in php

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm using real field in MS SQL to keep numbers with different resolution.
Using SQL Managament Studio i retrieve correct values

```
INSERT INTO test (a) VALUES (2.2);
SELECT a FROM test;
result 2.2
```

In php using sqlsrv functions i retrieve 22.200000762939
Is there any way to retrieve correct values?

Comment: have you try to use standard numerical?

Comment: it is worse than real, in numeric I have to declare precision. So if I declare (10,3) and put 2,22 value I retrieve 2,220;

Comment: In Mathematics: 2.22 **is equal** to 2.220. It is also equal to 2.220000000000. You need to use PHP number formatting functions to round/truncate unnecessary decimal digits.

Comment: But i have different precision numbers in fields coresponding to one column. User can put 2, or 2.2, or 2.223 and should retrieve the same value. When i use pgsql i always have the same value, problem exists only with sql server.